# Javascript: hashtag regex not working

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following Regex in javascript to find all hashtags in a string:

```
string.match(/#([^\s]+)/g);
```

This works fine as long as the hashtag is not followed by an HTML tag.

https://regex101.com/r/pJ4wC5/139

Can anybody help?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `#([^\s<]+)`.

The `^\s...` is whatever you don't want matched. Right now it looks to just be whitespace. Adding `<` additionally says "don't match `<`"

Comment: No need to escape `<`.